# Joomla Virtuemart 2 plgVmOnSelectPayment()

Tags: php, events, joomla, virtuemart

How can I add a form or HTML output to `plgVmOnSelectPayment()`?
I see no documentation about that.
I don't know this event Virtuemart payment select works.
I want add after selection a form with input fields.
Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

The plgVmOnSelectPayment() from what I've reversed engineered doesn't give any output to the HTML, but you can modify the cart content with that event.

I was myself in need of adding a form after a particular payment method was selected (to guarantee some additional data being supplied). Depending on where you want it you can either edit the View for the cart and add an if-statement where you see if the particular payment method is chosen. And then later access this information from `plgVmConfirmedOrder()` (you can access it through the `$_POST` global.

(This is an untested theory)
If you want to add the information to the field you can access the display form and add information there through the `plgVmDisplayListFEPayment()` event. Look in the [`vmPSPlugin`](http://docs.virtuemart.net/api-vm2/d1/d9d/classvm_p_s_plugin.html) class to see how they manage it there. What I did was simply copy that to get an image into that form, but you should be able to add other things there as well. And then you might be able to access the information there through `plgVmOnSelectPayment()` and using the `$_POST` global.

As a fair warning. All this I've gotten through reverse engineering VirtueMart. So it's neither pictue perfect nor might it be best practice. But the VirtueMart documentation leave not many other options :(. So if someone have a better way, I'm very interested in knowing that as well!